# Add Javascript or CSS to KnowledgeArticle in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, css, dynamics-crm

When trying to add CSS or Javascript to a KnowledgeArticle in Dynamics CRM it strips it out, I did try originally to use the WebApi to do it programmatically but when that failed I tried in the designer as well and it seems to not like it, see following GIFs:

[image]
[image]

I have tried both as relative and absolute links to CRM web resources and external sites, but both are stripped. How can I use CSS or JavaScript in a KnowledgeArticle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Straight answer: you can't. It would introduce serious security issues.